# I want to play a multiple sound files base on queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to play multiple sound files on my webpage based on queue order, example I have queue order like 1.wav 2.wav 3.wav, then I have my database to store the voice for each word 0-9.

I'm trying to create simple script to play sound in order on a single button click.

PLAY->1.wav -> END:PLAY-> 2.wav -> END:PLAY-> 3.wav -> END

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I herd you liek recursion!

```
//This plays a file, and call a callback once it completed (if a callback is set)

function play(audio, callback) {

audio.play();
if(callback)
{
    audio.onended = callback;
}
}
```

This gets an array of audio objects and actually impements the queue

```
function queue_sounds(sounds){

    var index = 0;
    function recursive_play()
    {
      if(index+1 === sounds.length)
      {
        play(sounds[index],null);
      }
      else
      {
        play(sounds[index],function(){index++; recursive_play();});
      }
    }

recursive_play();   
}
```

So you actually do something like this:

```
queue_sounds([new Audio(foo), new Audio(bar), new Audio(lol)]);
```

Comment: Filenames in quotes for starters, and put the queue_sounds after the function definitions

Comment: Still don't work on jsfiddle.com I get IE error: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; User-agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; http://bsalsa.com) ; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Mon, 27 Feb 2012 18:05:46 UTC
Message: 'Audio' is undefined
Line: 70
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/

Comment: It must be your files because the script fails on the audio.play() method on FF... Try with all major formats (mp3, ogg and wav) to see if that fixes it. Also do some reading on the canPlayType method of the audio object to find a way to let the JS pick the proper file automatically :)